# Performance recursive lookup function C#

Tags: c#, recursion

We have the following recursive function which is used for looking up the member objects, which are listed in the following property of the group object. We use the group list for the recursive check in the groups.

This function with approximately 30k users and 40k groups takes about 20 minutes to run, which we want to speed up. Any ideas how to do this more efficient?

```
foreach (ad_group_source group in group_source)
{
    List<ad_user_source> list = FindMembers(group, group_source, user_source);
}

public static List<ad_user_source> FindMembers(ad_group_source group, HashSet<ad_group_source> group_source, HashSet<ad_user_source> user_source)
{
    List<String> members = group.Members.Split(';').ToList();
    if (members.Equals(""))
    {
        return new List<ad_user_source>();
    }
    List<ad_user_source> members2 = new List<ad_user_source>();
    foreach (String member in members)
    {
        if (!member.Equals(""))
        {
            Boolean isUser = false;
            ad_user_source gebruiker = user_source.FirstOrDefault(u => u.DistinguishedName == member);
            if (gebruiker != null)
            {
                members2.Add(gebruiker);
                isUser = true;
            }
            if (!isUser)
            {
                ad_group_source group2 = group_source.FirstOrDefault(g => g.CN == member.Substring(3));
                if (group2 != null)
                {
                    List<ad_user_source> l = FindMembers(group2, group_source, user_source);
                    members2.AddRange(l);
                }
            }
         }

     }
     List<ad_user_source> members3 = members2.Distinct().ToList();
     return members3;
 }
```

Comment: "Making things faster" is not the greatest question in the world here, since it's likely to only apply to your code and not be helpful to others. If you want a review of your entire code, and provide example data, this *might* be okay on [codereview.se], but read their help center before asking.

Comment: Is it worth to cache this operation?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Why should it not help anyone? I'm using a recursive function that is not performing?

Comment: I see **a lot** wrong with this code.

Comment: Because the specifics of improving *your* code is not necessarily going to be the same as those changes necessary to improve others' code.

Comment: `members.Equals("")` never returns `true`, because string list and string have different types.

Comment: @maccettura: Can you give some hints?

Comment: Enumerating HashSets.  Doing nothing with your returned List in your foreach, too many unnecessary `ToList` calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code keeps using hash sets as if they were lists. This is very inefficient.

To address this problem construct a `Dictionary<string,ad_user_source>` organized by `DistinguishedName`, and `Dictionary<string,ad_group_source>` organized by `g.CN`. Don't put groups with `CN` that is longer than three characters, in case there are any in the original set.

Comment: Thanks for the direction to solve this. I will try it out and mark your answer as the solution if it works.

Comment: The use of Dictionaries have a huge performance boost. Thanks!